# Test intermediary state in async handler with React and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, assert

Despite reading the documentation of [enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme#react-hooks-support), and [act](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act), I could not find a response to my use case because the examples only show simple use cases.

I have a React component displaying a button. The `onClick` handler sets a loading boolean and calls an external API. I want to assert that the component shows the loading indicator when we click on the button.

Here is the component:

```
export default function MyButton(): ReactElement {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState<any>(null);

    const onClick = async (): Promise<void> => {
        setLoading(true);

        const response = await fetch('/uri');
        setData(await response.json());

        setLoading(false);
    };

    if (loading) {
        return <small>Loading...</small>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}>Click Me!</button>

            <div>
                {data}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the test:

```
test('should display Loading...', async () => {
    window.fetch = () => Promise.resolve({
        json: () => ({
            item1: 'item1',
            item2: 'item2',
        }),
    });

    const component = mount(<MyButton />);

    // Case 1 ✅ => validates the assertion BUT displays the following warning
    component.find('button').simulate('click');
    // Warning: An update to MyButton inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    // When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    // act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    // });
    /* assert on the output */
    // This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at [URL to fb removed because SO does not accept it]

    // Case 2 ❌ => fails the assertion AND displays the warning above
    act(() => {
        component.find('button').simulate('click');
    });

    // Case 3 ❌ => fails the assertion BUT does not display the warning
    await act(async () => {
        component.find('button').simulate('click');
    });

    expect(component.debug()).toContain('Loading...');
});
```

As you can see, if I get rid of the warning, my test is not satisfying anymore as it waits for the promise to resolve. How can we assert the intermediate state change while using `act`?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the element is not in the output at all. Not that I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just resolve promise manually:

```
const mockedData = {
  json: () => ({
    item1: 'item1',
    item2: 'item2',
  }),
};
let resolver;
window.fetch = () => new Promise((_resolver) => {
  resolver = _resolver;
});

// ....
await act(async () => {
  component.find('button').simulate('click');
});
expect(component.debug()).toContain('Loading...');
resolver(mockedData);
expect(component.debug()).not.toContain('Loading...');
```

PS but in sake of readability I'd rather have 2 separate tests: one with `new Promise();` that never resolves and another with `Promise.resolve(mockedData)` that would be resolved automatically

Comment: Good catch! Thanks. Agreed with the two separate tests. I also had to add a `component.update()` for the unresolved promise test in order to update the component before assertion. All good.